# Uma div sobreposta a uma imagem desce de acordo com a barra de rolagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, apache-cordova

Tenho uma div que mostra alguns detalhes sobre uma imagem quando ela é exibida, porem estou desenvolvendo para mobile e quando se da um slide para baixo as divs que contem esses detalhes também se mechem saindo de cima das imagens.

Segue o link do projeto no gitHub.

LINK : https://github.com/bleekbless/ProjetoPi2.0/tree/master/projetopi/www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu amigo, dei uma olhada no teu codigo. 
Em primeiro lugar vi que tinham varios " id " iguais, te aconselho de usar uma classe(mudando tambem o css):

## File touchTouch.jquery.js

```
$('<div class="dadosRoupa">').html(text);
```

Outra coisa que notei era que descia por causa desse codigo aqui:

```
var $spanInPlace = target.find("div"),
            $targetImage = target.find('img'),
            distanceBot  = target.height() - $targetImage.offset().top - $targetImage.height();

        $spanInPlace.css({"bottom": distanceBot+"px"});
```

Eu mudaria para:

```
   $spanInPlace.css({"bottom": "0px"});
```

Assim pega sempre a mesma posiçao.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muuuito obrigado... deu certinho !! *0*

Comment: De nada, da um ok na resposta. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar uma div q acompanhe a barra, deve setá-la com position: fixed;
 assim o ponto top: x ou bottom: x do css, ficarão fixo, mesmo q desça a barra de rolagem.